# Al oprimir un input tipo submit, se me resetea el formulario

Tags: php

Cordial saludo.
Actualmente estoy desarrollando un formulario para que una empresa registre la jornada diaria de sus colaboradores, los cuales pueden ser de diferentes departamentos o areas, para lo cual, estoy haciendo unas pruebas. El formulario tiene dos input tipo Submit. El primero se oprime para que se genere el formulario a diligenciar y luego de diligenciar el formulario con los horarios de trabajo y la descripción de las actividades, se oprime el segundo input tipo Submit para que valide los datos ingresados.
Al oprimir el primer input todo funciona bien y se genera el formulario a diligenciar, pero al oprimir el segundo input, no ingresa a las validaciones tipo if, sino que borra todo lo que había. No he podido entender porque pasa eso, ya que lo que yo esperaba, era que ingresara a las validaciones if para identificar si registro toda la información o si le falto algo.
Este es el código que me esta presentando lo mencionado:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Registros Jornada Laboral</title>
        <!--esto es necesario para poder usar la hoja de estilos-->
        <link href="Estilos.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Administracion-Registro-Jornadas-Jefe</h3>
        <form method="post" action="">
            fecha jornada: <input type="date" name="FecJor" size="3" value="<?php echo isset($_POST["FecJor"]) ? $_POST["FecJor"] : ""?>"/> <p />
            tipo de jornada: <br />
                ALMACEN<input cheked value="ALMACEN" type="radio" name="TipJor"/>
                CONDUCTOR<input cheked value="CONDUCTOR" type="radio" name="TipJor"/>
                GRUA<input cheked value="GRUA" type="radio" name="TipJor"/>
                MONTAJES<input cheked value="MONTAJES" type="radio" name="TipJor"/>
                PINTURA<input cheked value="PINTURA" type="radio" name="TipJor"/>
                TALLER<input cheked value="TALLER" type="radio" name="TipJor"/> <p />
            <input type="submit" value="ejecutar" name="a"/>
        </form>
        <!--a partir de este momento validamos si los datos ingresados son correctos-->
        <?php
            //es la accion que se ejecutará al oprimir el boton ejecutar y tener datos en la array $_POST["a"]
            if ($_POST["a"]) { 
                //asigno varibles los elementos de $_POST["a"]
                $FecJor=$_POST['FecJor'];
                $TipJor=$_POST['TipJor'];
                $NumCed=$_POST['NumCed'];               
                if ($FecJor=="") {
                    echo "ingrese la fecha de la jornada por favor";
                }   
                else if ($TipJor=="") {
                    echo "ingrese el tipo de jornada";
                }   
                else {  
        ?>      
                    <form method="post" action="">
                        <!--por el momento, esto nos permitira validar la informacion de cualquier colaborador-->
                        <table id="TableSalidaLlanta" style="margin: 0 auto;">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr> 
                                    <td class="TablaCampos" colspan="8" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">REGISTRO JORNADA DIARIA</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr> 
                                    <td class="TablaCampos">HORA_INICIO</td>
                                    <td class="TablaCampos">HORA_FIN</td>
                                    <td class="TablaCampos">DESCRIPCION_LABOR</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr> 
                                    <td><input type="time" name="HorIni" value="<?php echo isset($_POST["HorIni"]) ? $_POST["HorIni"] : ""?>"/></td>
                                    <td><input type="time" name="HorFin" value="<?php echo isset($_POST["HorFin"]) ? $_POST["HorFin"] : ""?>"/></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="DesLab" value="<?php echo isset($_POST["DesLab"]) ? $_POST["DesLab"] : ""?>"/></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody> 
                        </table>    
                        <!--con este input, asignamos los valores al array $_POST["c"]-->
                        <input type="submit" value="ejecutar" name="c"/>
                    </form>
        <?php
                        //validamos la informacion registrada
                        if ($_POST["c"]) {
                            $HorIni=$_POST['HorIni'];
                            $HorFin=$_POST['HorFin'];
                            $DesLab=$_POST['DesLab'];
                            if ($HorIni=="") {
                                echo "ingres la hora de inicio por favor";
                            }
                            else if ($HorFin=="") {
                                echo "ingres la hora de finalizacion por favor";
                            }
                            else if ($DesLab=="") {
                                echo "ingres la descripcion de la labor por favor";
                            }
                            else {
                                echo "la informacion se encuentra correcta";
                            }           
                        }
                }
            }
        ?>      
    </body>
</html>
```

Agradecemos su ayuda

Comment: hiciste una depuracion paso a paso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cordial saludo. Luego de identificar que cada que oprimo el botón type submit, el array $_POST() se borra y se ingresan los nuevo valores, pudimos identificar que habían datos del primer submit que debían estar disponibles en el según.
Por ello, antes de ejecutar el segundo submit, dejamos disponibles en la el array $_POST() estos valores, así cuando ejecutamos el segundo submit, el $_POST() agrega los nuevos valores, pero conserva los anteriores. estas fueron las líneas que agregue antes del segundo submit:

```
                <input type="hidden" name="FecJor" value="<?php echo $_POST['FecJor'] ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="TipJor" value="<?php echo $_POST['TipJor'] ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="a" value="ejecutar">
```

el código completo, incluyendo la modificacion realizada, quedo asi:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Registros Jornada Laboral</title>
        <!--esto es necesario para poder usar la hoja de estilos-->
        <link href="Estilos.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Administracion-Registro-Jornadas-Jefe</h3>
        <form method="post" action="">
            fecha jornada: <input type="date" name="FecJor" size="3" value="<?php echo isset($_POST["FecJor"]) ? $_POST["FecJor"] : ""?>"/> <p />
            tipo de jornada: <br />
                ALMACEN<input <?php echo $_POST["TipJor"]=="ALMACEN" ? "checked" : "" ?> value="ALMACEN" type="radio" name="TipJor"/>
                CONDUCTOR<input <?php echo $_POST["TipJor"]=="CONDUCTOR" ? "checked" : "" ?> value="CONDUCTOR" type="radio" name="TipJor"/>
                GRUA<input <?php echo $_POST["TipJor"]=="GRUA" ? "checked" : "" ?> value="GRUA" type="radio" name="TipJor"/>
                MONTAJES<input <?php echo $_POST["TipJor"]=="MONTAJES" ? "checked" : "" ?> value="MONTAJES" type="radio" name="TipJor"/>
                PINTURA<input <?php echo $_POST["TipJor"]=="PINTURA" ? "checked" : "" ?> value="PINTURA" type="radio" name="TipJor"/>
                TALLER<input <?php echo $_POST["TipJor"]=="TALLER" ? "checked" : "" ?> value="TALLER" type="radio" name="TipJor"/> <p />
            <input type="submit" value="ejecutar" name="a"/>
        </form>
        <!--a partir de este momento validamos si los datos ingresados son correctos-->
        <?php
            //es la accion que se ejecutará al oprimir el boton ejecutar y tener datos en la array $_POST["a"]
            if ($_POST["a"]) { 
                //asigno varibles los elementos de $_POST["a"]
                $FecJor=$_POST['FecJor'];
                $TipJor=$_POST['TipJor'];
                $NumCed=$_POST['NumCed'];               
                if ($FecJor=="") {
                    echo "ingrese la fecha de la jornada por favor";
                }   
                else if ($TipJor=="") {
                    echo "ingrese el tipo de jornada";
                }   
                else {  
        ?>      
                    <form method="post" action="">
                        <!--por el momento, esto nos permitira validar la informacion de cualquier colaborador-->
                        <table id="TableSalidaLlanta" style="margin: 0 auto;">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr> 
                                    <td class="TablaCampos" colspan="8" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">REGISTRO JORNADA DIARIA</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr> 
                                    <td class="TablaCampos">HORA_INICIO</td>
                                    <td class="TablaCampos">HORA_FIN</td>
                                    <td class="TablaCampos">DESCRIPCION_LABOR</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr> 
                                    <td><input type="time" name="HorIni" value="<?php echo isset($_POST["HorIni"]) ? $_POST["HorIni"] : ""?>"/></td>
                                    <td><input type="time" name="HorFin" value="<?php echo isset($_POST["HorFin"]) ? $_POST["HorFin"] : ""?>"/></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="DesLab" value="<?php echo isset($_POST["DesLab"]) ? $_POST["DesLab"] : ""?>"/></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody> 
                        </table>    
                        <!--con el type hidden, conservo los datos ingresados en el array POST del primer submit-->
                        <input type="hidden" name="FecJor" value="<?php echo $_POST['FecJor'] ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="TipJor" value="<?php echo $_POST['TipJor'] ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="a" value="ejecutar">
                        <!--con este input, asignamos los valores al array $_POST["c"]-->
                        <input type="submit" value="ejecutar" name="c"/>
                    </form>
        <?php
                        //validamos la informacion registrada
                        //print_r($_POST);
                        if ($_POST["c"]) {
                            $HorIni=$_POST['HorIni'];
                            $HorFin=$_POST['HorFin'];
                            $DesLab=$_POST['DesLab'];
                            if ($HorIni=="") {
                                echo "ingres la hora de inicio por favor";
                            }
                            else if ($HorFin=="") {
                                echo "ingres la hora de finalizacion por favor";
                            }
                            else if ($DesLab=="") {
                                echo "ingres la descripcion de la labor por favor";
                            }
                            else {
                                echo "la informacion se encuentra correcta";
                            }           
                        }
                }
            }
        ?>      
    </body>
</html>
```